# Photo search results in Sharepoint 2010 display wrong server

Tags: 2010, search-results

Recently I configured a Sharepoint site for a client, and it's working pretty well.

Except the picture search feature.

---

[image: Everything is fine, except for picture searching :<]

---

The picture should point to:
"http://www.contoso.com/sites/conglom-o/Beeldbank/_t/MH130925-BW047-LR.jpg"

Instead, it points to:
"http://contoso.local/sites/conglom-o/Beeldbank/_t/MH130925-BW047-LR.jpg"

Everything else works but those picture icons.

Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the web applications so that their Alternate Access Mappings would be consistent across zone. Use this article [SharePoint Search Result URL Mismatch](http://blog.sharepoint-voodoo.net/?p=82).

Comment: The URL's are fine, everything is fine. Those picture icons are the only thing that isn't displaying the right URL. Should I still do what is in that article?

Answer (score 0):

If you are CERTAIN that AAM is correct, which is usually the issue. Then you can correct this with Server Name Mapping, though if your AAMs are incorrect, you are only masking the issue. Are you crawling "www.cotoso.com" or "contoso.local" as the start address in your content source?